# Random InvalidOperationException: The property 'HotelName' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: c#, wpf

I konw that there are posts with similar issues. But my issue is a kind of strange one.

Development Enviornment: WPF + Entity Framework + SQL Express

When issue happens: It fails in my test code. when I run/debug the test methods one by one,  it does not happen; It happens when I debug/test the test methods, exception happens. You may think there are dependency between tests make it happens. But each of my test are independent with create environment-> setup up -> verify -> cleanup.

Issue:
- Exception: The property 'HotelName' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. 
- It may happen when I try to add the new customer record to the DB. code listed below:

```
        Customer customerInstance = null;
        try
        {
            customerInstance = new Customer();

            customerInstance.FirstName = firstName;
            customerInstance.SurName = lastName;
            customerInstance.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            customerInstance.ID = ID;
            customerInstance.IDTypeID = IDTypeID;

            m_HotelDB.Customers.Add(customerInstance);  //m_HotelDB is a DBContext
            m_HotelDB.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SysLog.Log(LogType.ERROR, "Add customer error: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

The ex.Message is "The property 'HotelName' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified". It is quite strange for me, since the "HotelName" is totally has no relationship with custmer object. It exists in Dictionary_Hotel, which has no relationship with Customer table, and I have no code in the whole project to update this property.

Do you get this kind of issue before? Thank you in advance, if you have any idea.
Happy New year!

---

Some update:
I found that "HotelName" is part of a view I created. I have a view that have the customer information and Hotel information.
When I try to add a customer record, it seems that Entity Framework trying to update the view correspondingly, which has the HotelName field. It is strange.
Any clue?